# How to use Runtime.getRuntime().exec in a web Applet to execute a jar file

Tags: java, jar, applet

So I tried to start notepad with a self signed Applet in browser. It works fine

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad");
```

but if I want to start another jar file

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar acceleration_de.jar");
```

it only works if I execute the jar directly. If I open the Applet in browser like I did as I started notepad it doesn't work. Why?

I have the suspicion that it could be somehow because the Applet is located somewhere different than the jar is if executed in browser. They are in same filepath of course.

Any idea how I can start the jar anyway?

Comment: *They are in same filepath of course*: what does that mean? You realize that the applet is downloaded from the server, and executed on the client machine? So, it the jar is on the server, there is no way the applet is able to find it. The jar must be on the client machine, and you must pass the absolute path to the jar.

Comment: Ok you are correct. At moment I'm only doing it on my own localhost. But even then the filepath of the jar I execute as applet and the filepath where it is executed are different ok good then I have the answere. I guess the only solution to do this is then downloading the jar in the applet itself and then execute it.

Comment: Why not use Java webstart instead? That's what it's for: downloading Java applications from a server and execute them, directly from the browser.

Comment: I want to use the Applet because the user then don't need to download something. The Applet starts, downloads the jar and execute it. It is the more elegant solution for me.

Comment: That's exactly what Webstart does. Except it allows starting real applications, and start them offline.

Comment: Well, it's been a long time ago since I did JavaApplets - but aren't they sandboxed and limited in functionality to prevent exactly the execution of arbitrary code by the applet?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [the docs regarding applet sandboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html).